# How to set windbg as postmortem debugger for elevated applications?

Tags: windbg

I have windbg registered as postmortem debugge (via `-I` command-line switch) and all works fine for non-elevated applications. But if elevated applications crashes, `windbg` starts and displays "Could not attach to process. Access is denied" error. Is it possible to somehow configure `windbg` so it will work as postmortem debugger for elevated apps?

Comment: That is odd, the post mortem debugger usually runs at the same privileges as the app that crashes so there should be no problem with it attaching, are you debugging a 32-bit or 64 bit app and have you configured the correct version of WinDbg? Sounds silly but you have registered 32-bit for 32-bit crashes and 64-bit WinDbg for 64-bit apps?

Comment: I have registered 64-bit WinDbg and using 32-bit app. Can it be a problem? If so, is it possible to have both 32-bit and 64-bit postmortem debuggers?

Comment: I think so, not honestly tried that but see if registering the 32-bit app resolves your immediate problem, sorry it's late in my timezone but these links may be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff542967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Try using [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to capture the stack trace for the access denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that it's an x86 app on an x64 system, you need to set these regkeys in Wow6432Node:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="\"C:\\debuggers\\windbg.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld -g"
"Auto"="1"
```

Note that these are both string values (`REG_SZ`) and I'm assuming that the windbg.exe is installed in `C:\debuggers`. Change that as appropriate.

Comment: That's pretty much the effect of using the `-i` command line switch.

Comment: I traced  `windbg -I` command using procmon, it adds the `wow6432node` reg keys.

Comment: When I ran `windbg -I` it only added the 64bit regkey. I had to manually add the above in the Wow6432Node.

Comment: My vershion 6.12.0002.633 AMD64